# Why was my edit that added more information rejected?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

While searching for how to create a sliding window in Rx.NET, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15256557/4397397) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22186145/4397397).

The answer told me what to do, but it didn't explain *why* it works. I looked through some documentation and worked out why the answer would work, so I thought it would be a good idea to edit the answer to provide some more information.

The [edit was rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18419665) by two people with the same reason:

> This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.

I don't understand why my edit should have been a comment, as it certainly wasn't intended to address the author. In my opinion it improves the answer by explaining *how* it solves the problem.

Is there something I should have done differently? Should I have phrased my edit differently?

Comment: Reviewers reject anything that has lots of green or red on pure kneejerk reaction. Meta supports such reactions while ignoring whatever benefit for the reader such edits could have. The author ultimately just deserve respect. That's the only thing that the guidance ask you for. You improved the answer out of respect of the author and made "the post significantly better when you edit", you were right and if I knew or had the time to investigate, I would apply your edit. (note that this comments implies that I would skip reviewing this edit on principle, too)

Comment: Also note, the author can override the decision of the reviewers, so long nobody else touches the answer,

Answer (score 9):

You probably should've posted a new answer.

Edits are mostly meant to fix problems in a question or answer. Not to expand an answer like you did.

See [SO's help page on the editing privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit):

> Some common reasons to edit are:
>
> - to fix grammatical or spelling mistakes
> - to clarify the meaning of a post without changing it
> - to correct minor mistakes or add addendums / updates as the post ages
> - to add related resources or hyperlinks

Comment: "to clarify the meaning of a post without changing it". Isn't that what I was doing? If I posted a new answer, it only would have been providing the same solution.

Comment: _"without changing it"_ < don't overlook the second half of that line. _"Clarify"_, in that context, means slightly changing how something is said.

Comment: It didn't change it. The meat of the answer is the first line and that was left untouched. The rest could be not in the answer and the solution would be exactly the same.

Comment: @Braiam: I'm assuming _"without changing it"_ refers to the post, not just that line. You just don't make such significant changes to a answer.

Comment: Well, how can you edit a post without changing it? What shouldn't change is the meaning. Clarify the meaning without changing the meaning.

Comment: Imo, when you change an answer like that, that much, the meaning changes. It’s like it becomes a tutorial instead of a quick short answer.

Comment: Ok, explain to me, how the solution is orthogonal to what it was originally. Remember, the meaning of an answer is, well, answer the question in a determined way, and AFAIK, that way hasn't changed at all, isn't it?

Comment: _"the solution is **orthogonal**"_... wut? That's a word I haven't seen before... (?)